# Randomly move 'a' in an 2D array to a specify location while keeping track of the number of time it pass through each point

Tags: java, arrays, loops, random

I have this 2D array (say double[10][10]) which contain some 1.0 and 10.0, rest are all in 0.0s. I am trying to loop through this array to find the 1.0 (start point), from there 'move' it randomly (using random.nextInt(4)) up, down, left or right till it gets to 10.0. I created a emptyArray to keep track of how many time it had moved pass each point (or at least I think I did). Nothing came up when I compile but I do not get any result when I try to display it into a frame. Any idea where I had gone wrong or missing?

```
{0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0}
{0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0}
{0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0}
{0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0}
{0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0}
{0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0}
{0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0}
{0.0,10.0,10.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0}
{0.0,10.0,10.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0}
{0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0}
```

Sample of 2D array.

```
    double[][] getPath(double[][] dataIn) {
    double[][] emptyArray = new double[dataIn.length][dataIn[0].length];
    double[][] drunkLoc = new double[dataIn.length][dataIn[0].length];
    for (int i = 0; i < dataIn.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < dataIn[i].length; j++) {
            if (dataIn[i][j] == 1.0) {

                double drunkHome = 10.0;
                drunkLoc[i][j] = dataIn[i][j];
                do {
                    int dir = getDirection();
                    switch(dir) {
                        case 0: 
                            if ((i > 0) && (j > 0)) {
                                drunkLoc[i][j] = drunkLoc[i-1][j];
                                double value = emptyArray[i][j];
                                emptyArray[i][j] = value + 1;
                                emptyArray[i][j] = (255<<24)  | (255<<16) | (255<<8) | 255;
                            } else {
                                break;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 1: 
                            if ((i > 0) && (j > 0)) {
                                drunkLoc[i][j] = drunkLoc[i][j-1];
                                double value = emptyArray[i][j];
                                emptyArray[i][j] = value + 1;
                                emptyArray[i][j] = (255<<24)  | (255<<16) | (255<<8) | 255;
                            } else {
                                break;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 2: 
                            if ((i > 0) && (j > 0)) {
                                drunkLoc[i][j] = drunkLoc[i+1][j];
                                double value = emptyArray[i][j];
                                emptyArray[i][j] = value + 1;
                                emptyArray[i][j] = (255<<24)  | (255<<16) | (255<<8) | 255;
                            } else {
                                break;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 3: 
                            if ((i > 0) && (j > 0)) {
                                drunkLoc[i][j] = drunkLoc[i][j+1];
                                double value = emptyArray[i][j];
                                emptyArray[i][j] = value + 1;
                                emptyArray[i][j] = (255<<24)  | (255<<16) | (255<<8) | 255;
                            } else {
                                break;
                            }
                            break;
                        default:
                    }
                } while (drunkLoc[i][j] != drunkHome);
            }
        }
    }
    return emptyArray;
}
```

Do let me know if you need any more clarification. Only my second post so still learning on my questioning technique. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I haven't quite got my head round What You're Trying To Actually Do here but have you put logging in of the arrays on each iteration and compared the output to what you expect to happen?

Comment: Incidentally, your conditions "(i > 0) && (j > 0)" are wrong for dirs 1-3. Plus the bizarre lines with the shifts (why not just write "-1"?!?) will always overwrite the "value + 1" which I assume is not what you intended.

Comment: Hi @NeilCoffey, I am trying to get a return of array which contain the number of time 'a' passes through while getting from '1.0' to '10.0' randomly. I am new to java so don't quite understand what you mean by "put logging if of the array on each iteration", could you explain please. Thank you.

Comment: Oh the (i>0)&&((j>0) part for each of the 4 possible case is to prevent 'a' from running out of the array. Is this the right way?

Comment: To log out the contents of the array, do System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array)); Just before your line with 'while', call this on each of the arrays and see what it looks like.

Comment: But your arrays are actually pointless for your task. All you need are the *coordinates* of the destination (the "10") and the *coordinates* of the 'current' place, along with the count.

Comment: That's kinda what I need, I though by using an array I will be able to keep track of all these. I had been trying to get the coordinates of a position (let say first '1.0' in the loop) but could not get a working code, hence I try to use an array to store all these information. Any suggestion how I could get the coordinates of a specify location?

Comment: Tried to log out the contents of the array, all I got was 0.0s, endless of them. I had been facing this problem where I cannot seems to be able to change values in array once I had init it. Any idea where is that so? ><;

Comment: I think the fundamental problem is that your underlying approach is messy and incomprehensible. Start by expressing the problem that you are trying to solve in the simplest possible way, and then using the simplest approach that you can to solve that problem. Your problem essentially needs 4 ints to represent the destination and current coordinates, yet somehow you've ended up with 3 arrays... Have a look at the sample code I've posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, for you to study, here's some sample code that will give you the answer you're looking for (the number of moves to get from (xpos,ypos) to (destX,destY) on a "board" that is penDimension x penDimension in size:

```
        int penDimension = 10;
        int destX = 2;
        int destY = 2;
        int xpos = 5;
        int ypos = 5;

        // Add this to keep track of no moves through each square
        int[][] moveCounts = new int[penDimension][penDimension];

        Random r = new SecureRandom();
        long noMoves = 0;
        while (xpos != destX || ypos != destY) {
            switch (r.nextInt(4)) {
            case 0 : xpos++; break;
            case 1 : xpos--; break;
            case 2 : ypos++; break;
            case 3 : ypos--; break;
            }
            if (xpos < 0) xpos = 0;
            if (ypos < 0) ypos = 0;
            if (xpos > penDimension) xpos = penDimension;
            if (ypos > penDimension) ypos = penDimension;
            noMoves++;

            // Add this to keep track of no moves through each square
            moveCounts[ypos][xpos]++;

        }
        System.out.println("Number of moves: " + noMoves);
```

Instead of doing ++ or -- and then checking the bounds afterwards, you could also write (and in real life probably would write) e.g.:

```
xpos = Math.max(0, xpos - 1);
```

I just wrote it as I did above because I thought it would be easier to understand.

Instead of writing "new SecureRandom()", you could also write "new Random()", which is probably what you've learnt. But SecureRandom is a much higher quality (but slower) random number generator. In general when writing 'simulations' where you are repeatedly generating a large number of random numbers, it's better to avoid the standard Random class and use a higher quality generator.

Comment: Nice, I will try this out, thanks a lot @Neil Coffey. But I am curious if I use this method above, is there a way I am able to count the number of time 'a' had moved through each individual point other than destination? Meaning I had to record the number of time 'a' moved pass each space before it reaches destination.

Comment: any advice how can I get the x,y of a specify cell in the array? For example if I would want to get the x,y of the first '1.0', how am I gonna do that? I though of using a for loop to go through rows and then column, set a if condition to match x,y == '1.0'. After which I am stuck, how do I return the x and y but not the value '1.0' in the x,y?

Comment: If you do need that, then create a single array and after you have moved the position, increment the value at that location. I'll update the code.